# One Graph problem

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph, the number of edges is the sum of the degrees of all vertices divide by 2. Explain why.

This is what I have:
Because there are $|V(G)|(|V(G)| - 1)$ possible such vertex pairs $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$. SO we need to divide this number by two.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the handshake lemma.  Each edge has two endpoints, and each endpoint contributes $1$ to the vertex degree. It thus follows that the sum of degrees of vertices divided by $2$ takes away the repeats and gives the number of edges.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.